# Php array and json

Tags: php, json

help me to convert the following array in to json.
I tried to convert the array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [c_code] => 200001
        [itemname] => 303 10CAP
        [c_pack_code] => PK0075
        [c_web_img_link] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [c_code] => 200005
        [itemname] => 3P 4TAB
        [c_pack_code] => 
        [c_web_img_link] => 
    )
)
```

current result for the following code is

```
 public function searchOrder($idx, $data) {

    if (!empty($data)) {            


        $result = OrderbukModel::func_get_searchlist($idx,$data);
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $resultArray[] = $result;
            print_r(json_encode($result));
        } else {
            $resultArray[$idx] = ["Mysql returns empty result !"];
            print_r(json_encode($resultArray));
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

now i got the result is like

```
[{"c_code":"200001","itemname":"303 10CAP","c_pack_code":"PK0075","c_web_img_link":""},{"c_code":"200005","itemname":"3P 4TAB","c_pack_code":"","c_web_img_link":""}]
```

But I need the result as follows

```
[{"c_code":"2000001","c_code":"200005"},
{"itemname":"303 10CAP","itemname":"3P 4TAB"},
{"c_pack_code":"PK0075","c_pack_code":""},
{"c_web_img_link":"","c_web_img_link":""}]
```

Comment: Okey its possible, just make two different array and at the end merge them and encode them

Comment: What you're trying to do is obviously more than a simple conversion to JSON since you already did that and are not satisfied.  In this case, you would need to do it yourself with a `foreach`.  Show us your best attempt either by answering your own question if you succeed or as additional information if it fails.

Comment: I can give you an example with your array, should i??

Comment: Thanks please give I will try @ Frayne Konok

Comment: This is something like i did: [https://3v4l.org/kdPDI](https://3v4l.org/kdPDI)

Comment: Remember what you want is not a valid json.

Comment: Thanks alot I got the idea I will make it..@Frayne Konok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how you can you make the json from array. Collect the data in two different array and after loop marge them and store the result in another array after that encode them.

> Note: Your desired JSON is not a valid format, you can't use same index
>   for two data.

Online Example: https://3v4l.org/kdPDI

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'c_code' => '200001',
        'itemname' => '303 10CAP',
        'c_pack_code' => 'PK0075',
        'c_web_img_link' => ''
    ),
    array(
        'c_code' => '200005',
        'itemname' => '3P 4TAB',
        'c_pack_code' => '',
        'c_web_img_link' => ''
    )
);

$res1 = array();
$res2 = array();
foreach($arr as $val){
    $res1['c_code'][] = $val['c_code'];
    $res1['itemname'][] = $val['itemname'];

    $res2['c_pack_code'][] = $val['c_pack_code'];
    $res2['c_web_img_link'][] = $val['c_web_img_link'];
}

$out = array(array_merge($res1, $res2));

echo json_encode($out);
```